# Angular, update view long calculations

Tags: angular, view, components, refresh

I'm facing a problem trying to implement a spinner with Angular 4.

I have a complex application that runs complex and long calculations. before running the calculations I want to display a spinner. In order to do that:

1. I set a variable to "true" to show the spinner
2. I do the complex calculations
3. I set back the variable to "false" to hide the spinner

The problem is that the spinner won't show.

In the following example, I faked the complex method to facilitate the understanding.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eqo9cl

Can anyone have a clue on how to solve this ?

It seems that the view is not able to refresh before launching the calculations. We can also see that the "val" variable is not updated in the view until the calculations are done.

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow the browser the opportunity to update the view before the calculations start, you can run them asynchronously with `setTimeout`. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-whxt79) for a demo.

```
doWork() {
  this.spinner = true;
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.performCalculations();
    this.spinner = false;
  }, 50);
}
```